# Qt5 create an exe file

Tags: c++, dll, qt5, exe

I'm trying to create a Qt5 executable on Windows, when I built the project from QtCreator and went to the build folder and started the **.exe** I received a lot of missing library errors, and I fixed it using **windeployqt**:

```
>C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\windeployqt.exe App.exe
```

Then I had another problem:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).
```

And I simply solved it by installing **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013**. But now if I try to start it it gives me an error:

```
The code execution cannot continue because libwinpthread-1.dll was not found.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a description for this process (which is called deployment) in the Qt manual, e.g [deployment with windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html), you might also look at the [Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows) for manual deployment.

BUT: It looks as though you mixed up something in you application: Visual C++ Redistributable Packages are needed in case you compile your application with Microsoft compilers. libwinpthread-1.dll is needed in case you compile your application with mingw compiler.

Make sure that you are using the same compiler/linker for all libraries, sources and the pre-built binaries from Qt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did as you told me and now everything works correctly!